# Show only integers in matplotlib x-axis tickmarks

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

New to matplotlib and have created a simple line chart from a dataset constructed similar in principle to that below. We'll call that dataframe 'cardata'

```
|------- |--------|------------|---------|
|   id   | year   |  some_var  |  count  |                                               
---------|--------|------------|---------|
|   1    |  2016  |     car    |    1    |                                      
|   2    |  2016  |     car    |    1    |  
|   3    |  2017  |     car    |    1    |   
|   4    |  2017  |     car    |    1    |   
|   5    |  2018  |     car    |    1    |                                      
|   6    |  2018  |     car    |    1    |  
|   7    |  2018  |     car    |    1    |   
|   8    |  2019  |     car    |    1    | 
|   9    |  2019  |     car    |    1    | 
|  10    |  2020  |     car    |    1    |
```

I wish to aggregate the counts by year so that I can see how many times 'car' occurs per year.

I have achieved this using the following code

```
cardata.groupby(['year']).count()['some_var'].plot()
```

This gives me a plot I can use, however the x-axis goes like this...

```
| 2016 | 2016.5 | 2017 | 2017.5 | 2018 | 2018.5 | etc etc
```

Question 1) How can I set the x-asxis labels/tickmarks to only show integers for the year?

Question 2) How would I exclude the year '2020' for example, from the plot?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

boolean indexing, groupby and plot with the param xticks:

```
g = df[df['year'] != 2020].groupby('year').count()['some_var']
g.plot(xticks=g.index)
```

One way of plotting labels is to use matplotlib and list comprehension. The code blow will plot the `y` value but it could really be anything:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
g = df[df['year'] != 2020].groupby('year').count()['some_var']

g.plot(xticks=g.index)

[plt.annotate(y, (x,y), textcoords="offset points",
              xytext=(0,10), ha='center') for x,y in list(zip(g.index, g))]
```

[image]

Comment: This is superb, thanks @Chris.
One more question if I may. How would I add labels to the datapoints?